# Forking project

Tags: blockchain, web3j

Currently im trying to fork a project, im experiencing a alot of compilation error specifically the versions.
What I did is just downloading the contract to remix, the issue comes up with the openzeppelin version and the contract i want to deploy. Is it not possible to deploy everything the same exact as the contract im forking? Because i feel like the openzeppelin .npn is automatically added when i click certain files i forked

Comment: Please add more details about compilation errors encountered, the versions of OpenZeppelin and other dependencies being used, and any other relevant details about the forking process and setup.